# Cast exception: HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl v javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, https, coldfusion

I'm getting a fussy runtime error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

This is the pertinent code.

```
final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(ALGORITHM_TLS_1_2);
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] {new TrustAllCertificates()}, new java.security.SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

// Install the all-trusting host verifier
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new TrustAllHosts());

// cookie connection
final URL authURL = new URL(data.getAuthURL());
final HttpsURLConnection httpsPost = (HttpsURLConnection) authURL.openConnection();
```

I tried backing off to HttpURLConnection, but my target system didn't appreciate it.

This code works fine locally, but throws the runtime exception when I try to implement it as an add on for a ColdFusion 2018 server.

The "URL" is java.net.URL and "data.getAuthURL()" is a string (returns a String, to be picky.)

I am assuming that authURL.openConnection() is "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl"

How do I convince it to use the correct implementation? (or solve the problem, otherwise if I'm not asking the right question)

Comment: I don't have any com.sun.net imports.  I did try creating the URL like this (which got rid of the error, but failed to connect from the server) final URL authURL = new URL(null, data.getAuthURL(),new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());

Comment: Everything I try seems to work fine running from the IDE, but nothing wants to work right running as a user lib under ColdFusion

Comment: Checking something else... I may have solved the problem and run into a network snafu -- checking on that now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular instance, I changed

this 
`final URL authURL = new URL(data.getAuthURL());`

to this
`final URL authURL = new URL(null, data.getAuthURL(),new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());`

This also required updating an access policy in the JRE at build time.

The problem was the environment. When loaded as a user library on the ColdFusion server you don't get the protocol implementation you might be expecting, you get the one the ColdFusion server is using.

The code in the original question would be correct in most environments. The kludge was needed here because I wasn't "allowed" to select the implementation.